# Appropriate to call CompletableFuture#join many times?

Tags: java, asynchronous

Within a class that serves resources that must first be loaded into memory, here is my pattern:

```
public class FooService {
    private final CompletableFuture<Void> loaded;
    public FooService() {
        this.loaded = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            // Do some task that shouldn't hold up constructing
        });
    }

    public Foo get(String bar) {
        this.loaded.join(); // Ensure we have loaded everything before continuing
        return something;
    }
}
```

Is it appropriate to use CompletableFuture in this way (calling join() many times on what will after a relatively short period be a completed future)? Or should I look to using a flag and wait/notify? The above approach is cleaner but CompletableFuture docs do not specify if it is alright to call join many times.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is valid. However, the code can be optimized in size by replacing `join` with `get`:

```
public class FooService {
    private final CompletableFuture<Void> loaded;
    public FooService() {
        this.loaded = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           // Do some task that shouldn't hold up constructing
            return something;
        });
   }

    public Foo get(String bar) {
        return this.loaded.get(); // Ensure we have loaded everything before continuing
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean optimized in size? Literally 1 less character? Unfortunately this won't compile because the get() method throws checked exceptions. Unless you have another reason this is not an improvement

Comment: @IvanG. the scope of the variable "something" is greatly narrowed. This reduces potential errors in parallel programs. And you really have to decide how to react to the errors in the procedure which does the loading. In your original solution, you simply ignored them, but it was not obvious from your code. If you really want to ignore errors, simply surround `get` with try-catch block, so that others can see that it is your intention.